# Hide div element on custom url

Tags: html, show-hide

I'm looking for a solution to **hide div element with php code** base on my different custom link. So that the div i want to hide is not appeared in html source.

I have two different "div"s in a single page. In order to make the page showing **div A** and hiding **div B**, i have created "**example.com/account/?Member=login**"(for showing div A while div b is not showing) and "**example.com/account/?Member=Signup**"(for showing div B while div A is not appear). But, the code what i'm using now is as stated below.

Code in my css:

```
.login {display:none;}
.signup {display:none;}
```

PHP on html file:

```
    <?
    $s=$_GET['Member'];
    if ($s=="Login") {
       echo ('<style>.login {display:block;}</style>');
       }
    ?>
    <?
    $s=$_GET['Member'];
    if ($s=="Signup") {
       echo ('<style>.signup {display:block;}</style>');
       }
    ?>

<div class="login">
<p>Login Form</p>
</div><!--login-->

<div class="signup">
<p>Signup Form</p>
</div><!--signup-->
```

With this method, both div are showing in html source, even though one of the div is not showing in web page.

I want the div to be hidden without showing in html code. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just only render the login on your conditions matching. i.e.

```
<? $s=$_GET['Member'];
if ($s!="Login") { ?>

   <div class="login">
    <p>Login Form</p>
    </div><!--login-->

  <?php } else {?>

    <div class="signup">
    <p>Signup Form</p>
    </div><!--signup-->

<? } ?>
```

The above assume you want to show one of the two possibilities, you'd need to change it to

```
  <? $s=$_GET['Member'];
    if ($s=="Login") { ?>

        <div class="login">
        <p>Login Form</p>
        </div><!--login-->

  <? } 

    $s=$_GET['Member'];
    if ($s=="Signup") { ?>

        <div class="signup">
        <p>Signup Form</p>
        </div><!--signup-->

  <? } ?>
```

if there is a posibility of showing none of them

Comment: Hi atmd, thanks for your solutions! I'm actually newbie in php coding. I am actually prefer to use the method A, but i would like to ask how to make it like if showing Div A on link A, then showing Div B on link B, or else show others content on other links but hiding the Div A & B?

Comment: "the div i want to hide is not appeared in html source" that's not possible with css, you'd need to do it on the server. display:none will remove if from the flow BUT it will still be in the html source

Comment: Hi atmd, I have just searched some info about php. There is a php rule like "if, elseif and else. How should i apply the this php function to my needs? Thanks!

Comment: if, elseif and else would be used if you have 3 different outcomes, so if there is a chance of no form being shown they yes if would be acceptable to use if elseif else

Comment: Hi atmd, i got it worked with the php rule that i mentioned in previous comment. By the way, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Clear you css and:

```
    <?
        $s=$_GET['Member'];
        if ($s=="Login") {
    ?>
<div class="login">
<p>Login Form</p>
</div><!--login-->
    <?
        }
        $s=$_GET['Member'];
        if ($s=="Signup") {
    ?>
<div class="signup">
<p>Signup Form</p>
</div><!--signup-->
    <?
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi Petres, thanks for your code too! I have voted for others because he provides multiple options. Thanks again! :)